# Challenges after Installation

Tags: installation, boot-failure

Just installed Windows XP on a clean laptop, then installed Ubuntu as a dual boot. It said installation was complete, then when I restart, all I get is this a blank screen with this on it...ending in a prompt. Please help.

```
Fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
/dev/sda5: clean, 140746/188416 files, 733804/752640 blocks
Initctl: Event failed
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor/d/disable: usr.bin/firefox
* Starting AppArmor profiles     [ OK ]
Speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
Checking for running unattended-upgrades:
* Starting Bluetooth     [ OK ]

*PulseAudio configured per-user sessions
Saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
[ OK ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Looks like a net-install or alternate install.  Some of the alternate installers leave you on the boot process screen because they expect you to know to press ctl-alt-fX to get to a terminal or f7 if you want a gui you installed.  I don't think this is a mainline install.

Comment: Can you also include the prompt? If it's the login prompt, login using the username/password you entered during boot and then enter `startX` as the command to start the GUI. If that solves the problem, comment here and we can tell you how to enable auto GUI login.